# A converge problem seems to related to Tauber theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, tauberian-theory

ps: Due to my poor English, I might describe my thought roughly.

> Suppose $\{a_n\} (n \ge 0)$ is a sequence consisting of non-negative numbers,
> and $\{a_n\}$ satisfies that forall $x > 0$, $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} e^{-nx} a_n$ is convergent.
> Calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x f(x)$.

My thought:

Let $S = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n (e^{-x}) ^{n}$

then $e^{-x}S = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{n-1} (e^{-x})^n$

so $S = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1})(e^{-x})^n + a_0$

so $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1})(e^{-x})^n + a_0
= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1})(e^{-x})^n + a_0$

and then I have been discouraged

can anyone give me some hints or the true answer?

any hints welcome.

Comment: It's easier to do $e^{-x}=r$ so you get an analytic function in the unit disc by hypothesis as the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ converges at each $r<1$ and then $x=\log r$ which is $r-1$ up to error of order $2$; then you need to see what happens with $(1-z)f(z)$

Answer (score 1):

Assume the sequence $a_n$ is convergent to $a.$ Then
$$xf(x)=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}a_n=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}[a_n-a]+a{x\over 1-e^{-x}}$$
The second term tends to $a.$ We will show that the first term tends to $0.$ Indeed, for a fixed $N$ we have
$$g(x):=x\left |\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}[a_n-a]\right|\le 
x\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}|a_n-a|\\
=x\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-nx}|a_n-a|+x\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-nx}|a_n-a|\\
\le x\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-nx}|a_n-a|+\left (\sup_{n\ge N}|a_n-a|\right )\,x\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-nx} \\
=x\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-nx}|a_n-a|+\left (\sup_{n\ge N}|a_n-a|\right )\,{x\over 1-e^{-x}}e^{-Nx}$$
Taking the limit $x\to 0^+$ gives
$$\limsup_{x\to 0^+}g(x)\le \sup_{n\ge N}|a_n-a|$$ As $N$ is arbitrary we get $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=0.$

When $a_n\to \infty$ we get
$$xf(x)\ge x\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-nx}a_n\ge \left (\inf_{n\ge N}a_n\right )\ x\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-nx}\\
=\left (\inf_{n\ge N}a_n\right )\ {x\over 1-e^{-x}}e^{-Nx}$$
Taking the limit gives
$$\liminf_{x\to 0^+}xf(x)\ge \inf_{n\ge N}a_n$$ As $N$ is arbitrary we get
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} xf(x)=\infty.$

**Remark** The assumptions can be relaxed to the existence of the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_0+a_1+\ldots +a_n\over n+1}$$

Comment: As a comment to the OP says, a change of variables at the start would make calculations look simpler. Set $y = e^{-x}$, so $x > 0$ is equivalent to $0 < y < 1$, $x \to 0^+$ is equivalent to $y \to 1^-$, and $f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_ny^n$ is a power series in $y$ that converges for $0 < y < 1$ (so also for $-1 < y < 1$). Set $F(y) =  \sum_{n \geq 0} a_ny^n$, so $xf(x) = -(\log y)F(y)$. Since $\log y \sim y-1$ as $y \to 1$, we have $\lim_{x \to 0^+} xf(x) = \lim_{y \to 1^-} (1-y)F(y)$, where $F(y)$ is a power series convergent on $|y| < 1$. This would avoid the ugly $e^{-x}$ terms everywhere.

Comment: Well, it is a matter of taste. The formulas are not  eseentially  shorter when we replace $e^{-x}$ by $z.$

Comment: Sure, it's all a matter of taste, but here are two examples of how the calculations simplify by setting it up as $\lim_{y \to 1^-}(1-y)F(y)$. (i) At the start, instead of $xa\sum_{n \geq 0} e^{-nx} = xa/(1-e^{-x})$ you'd have $(1-y)a\sum_{n \geq 0} y^n = a$, so the second term is literally $a$ right away, not just in the limit. (ii) In the  middle, instead of $x\sum_{n \geq N} e^{-nx} = xe^{-Nx}/(1-e^{-x})$ you'd have $(1-y)\sum_{n \geq N} y^n = y^N$.

Comment: thank you!thanks very much